# karate-gatling: How to exclude setup/create from simulation response time?

Tags: karate

I'm trying to set/enforce performance SLAs on endpoints for a service. Some of the tests have a create step which will create an account using an API call. The create step can take a second or two. I'm trying to measure/set assertions on the performance of the GET (~50ms) without including the time for the create (1-2 sec).

Using static feeder files with hard-coded IDs isn't ideal since we'd like to be able to run the test in transient environments, and we'd like to avoid the fragility from assuming:
1) a particular account exists 
2) no other process has tampered with it

An approach I'm considering: Set up a feeder which creates the account and then calls the feature file. The feeder could use the java API to call a feature file to create the account, but I'm not sure how to pass the created account id into the GET method. Could I use the gatling session for that?  (This is the part I need help with most)

Questions I can answer through experimentation after I can pass the account id:

I'm also not sure if the latency on the create response plays well with gatling feeders -- will it cause the simulation to fail? Is time for the feeder to create the account excluded from the simulation?.

How I'm currently running simulations (not with feeders yet)

```
class FooSimulation extends AbstractSim {
  override def urlPattern: String = "api/foo"

  override def karateFeaturePath: String = "classpath:foo.feature"
}

import com.intuit.karate.gatling.PreDef.{pauseFor, _}
import io.gatling.core.Predef.{global, _}

import scala.concurrent.duration._

abstract class AbstractSim extends Simulation {

  def secondMillis = 1000

  def urlPattern: String

  def karateFeaturePath: String

  def successThreshold = 99
  def simulationUsers = 20
  def simulationDurationSeconds = 20


  def percentiles: (Int, Int, Int, Int) =  {  ( 2 * secondMillis,   3 * secondMillis,  4 * secondMillis,  5 * secondMillis) }



  val protocol = karateProtocol(
    urlPattern -> Nil,
    urlPattern -> pauseFor("get" -> 0, "post" -> 0)
  )

  protocol.nameResolver = (req, ctx) => req.getHeader("karate-name")

  val theScenario = scenario(this.getClass.getName).exec(karateFeature(karateFeaturePath))

  val (p1, p2, p3, p4) = percentiles
  setUp(
    theScenario.inject(rampUsers(simulationUsers) over (simulationDurationSeconds seconds)).protocols(protocol),
  ).assertions(
    List(
      global.successfulRequests.percent.gte(successThreshold)
      , global.responseTime.mean.lte(p1)
      , global.responseTime.percentile1.lte(p1) //50th %
      , global.responseTime.percentile2.lte(p2) //75th %
      , global.responseTime.percentile3.lte(p3) //95th % //first request may require a cache rebuild which can take 2+ secs
      , global.responseTime.percentile4.lte(p4) //99th % //first request may require a cache rebuild which can take 2+ secs
    )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest [karate-gatling-demo](https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-gatling-demo) example has an example of using a "setup" routine - in this case a Karate feature file itself (that can theoretically use `karate-config.js` for environment switching). And the setup routine drives a feeder which passes data into all the main features.

Maybe you have seen it already, but the very latest 0.9.2 version added some documentation on feeders: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#feeders

Note there is an open feature request to be able to mark some feature files as "silent" so that they don't contribute to the final report / throughput: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/707